# Propagating class decorators to inherited classes

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

```
import inspect
import functools

def for_all_test_methods(decorator):
    def decorate(cls):
        for name, value in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isroutine):
            if name.startswith('test'):
                setattr(cls, name, test_decorator(getattr(cls, name)))
        return cls
    return decorate

def test_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__name__, args, kwargs)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return wrapper

@for_all_test_methods(test_decorator)
class Potato(object):
    def test_method(self):
        print('in method')

class Spud(Potato):
    def test_derived(self):
        print('in derived')
```

Now if I create a spud instance the `test_method` which it has inherited remains decorated, but it has an undecorated method `test_derived`.  Unfortunately, if I add the class decorator onto `Spud` aswell, then his `test_method` gets decorated twice!

How do I correctly propagate decorators from the parent class onto the children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can accomplish this by using a metaclass instead of decorating the class:

```
import inspect
import functools

def test_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__name__, args, kwargs)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return wrapper

def make_test_deco_type(decorator):
    class TestDecoType(type):
        def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
            for name, value in dct.items():
                if name.startswith('test') and inspect.isroutine(value):
                    dct[name] = decorator(value)
            return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)
    return TestDecoType

class Potato(object, metaclass=make_test_deco_type(test_decorator)):
    def test_method(self):
        print('in method')

class Spud(Potato):
    def test_derived(self):
        print('in derived')
```

On Python 2.x you would use `__metaclass__ = make_test_deco_type(test_decorator)` as the first line of the class body instead of having the `metaclass=...` portion of the class statement.  You would also need to replace `super()` with `super(TestDecoType, cls)`.

Comment: This looks nicer than the route I was heading down.  How do you handle the `super` line on python2?

Comment: But self is not defined at that time.  Do I use `super(TestDecoType, cls)`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid decorating derived classes; you can find subclasses of a class after subclasses have been decorated, but not auto-decorate them. Use a metaclass instead of you need that sort of behaviour.

You can do one of two things:

1. Detect already-decorated methods; if there is a `__wrapped__` attribute you have a wrapper:

   ```
   def for_all_test_methods(decorator):
       def decorate(cls):
           for name, value in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isroutine):
               if name.startswith('test') and not hasattr(value, '__wrapped__'):
                   setattr(cls, name, test_decorator(getattr(cls, name)))
           return cls
       return decorate
   ```
2. Limit the class decorator to *direct* methods only:

   ```
   def for_all_test_methods(decorator):
       def decorate(cls):
           for name, value in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
               if name.startswith('test') and inspect.isroutine(value)):
                   setattr(cls, name, test_decorator(getattr(cls, name)))
           return cls
       return decorate
   ```

Comment: This, sir, is one great answer.

Comment: 1.  Couldn't `__wrapped__` have already been set by some other decorator?  2.  Then I will need to decorate the derived class aswell?

Comment: @wim: Yes, `__wrapped__` could have been set by another decorator. You **certainly** have to decorate derived classes.